# How to extract an array with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a list from a script tag in an html file.
How do I extract the list called markers from the script tag ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import re
import json


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('url').content, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
txt = scripts[22]
print(txt)
```

The returned data ( value of txt ) is in the following format

```
<script>jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"en\/","setHasJsCookie":0,"ajaxPageState, "markers":[{"latitude":"49.123","longitude":"-123.000","title":"point of interest"}] <script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  markers isn't a list.... or an array

Comment: This might be a bit of a hack, but what if you just used substring to remove the first  and lastpart and parsed it as JSON? E.g. `json.loads(str(txt)[22:-8])` ?

Comment: @Alexander well the value of markers is a list. I don't understand what you mean by  expected output. I only need the value of markers.

Comment: @NickODell I've scrapped a large part of the output for brevity so I'm afraid the substring solution won't really work.

Comment: actually it still isn't a list or an array... look at the brackets and braces... they aren't balanced...  you cant have a `[{ ... ]}`  It also looks like your missing a quote just before "markers" ,

Comment: my bad. it was a typo when editing. fixed now.

Comment: yes the list is always in the same format "markers":[...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex is probably your best bet

```
import re
import json

txt = '<script>jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"en\/","setHasJsCookie":0,"ajaxPageState, "markers":[{"latitude":"49.123","longitude":"-123.000","title":"point of interest"}] <script>'

pattern = re.findall(r'"markers":(\[.*?\])\s<script>', txt)
lst = json.loads(pattern[0])
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'latitude': '49.123', 'longitude': '-123.000', 'title': 'point of interest'}]
```